# Trying to compose in CSS Modules with @import from node_module

Tags: webpack, postcss, css-modules

Using css modules in webpack 2, I am not able to use `composes` in a component `scss` file if I'm trying to compose from another file that imports from `node_modules` using a tilde.

The error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables' in '/[PATH_TO_SRC]/styles/bootstrap'
```

Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/morgs32/f5c77a56e5f5612c543f693350917080

#### ./exandableTable

```
.expandableTable {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -36px;
  composes: table from './tables.scss';
  background: #eee;
}
```

#### ./tables.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables';
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/tables';

.table {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Using `styles from './tables.scss` and `styles.table` works just fine.

As does `styles from './expandableTable.scss'` **WITHOUT** the `composes`

Thanks for any insight! Happy to share my webpack config...